# set session when send posts data from external website via curl to action controller

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, laravel-session

I using a code in my Home Controller :

```
public function myAction1(Request $request)
{
   $request->session()->put('redirect', $_POST['redirect']);
}

public function myAction2(Request $request)
{
   $request->session()->get('redirect');
}
```

and this is part of my `route` :

```
Route::get('pGetway/send', 'HomeController@myAction1')->middleware('cors');
Route::post('pGetway/send', 'HomeController@myAction1')->middleware('cors');

Route::get('pGetway/verify', 'HomeController@myAction2')->middleware('cors');
Route::post('pGetway/verify', 'HomeController@myAction2')->middleware('cors');
```

when I use HTTP request from browser thats `session` working well but when sending data from other website via `curl` it not working mean session did not set !!

I want set sesstion and using that from other action for example in `myAction2`

and this is curl request post:

```
$params = ['redirect'=>'http://example.com'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8000/pGetway/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should set curl cookies file and cookies jar to use it with session

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain further about that. how to set the cookie and take it from action controller?

Comment: curl give you some methods to work with cookies locally without a browser. Example

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: test=cookie"));